# Is there a method of initiating a ThinBox<[T]>?

Tags: rust, language-features, nightly-build

I have been dabbling in experimental features lately and have been using them for a library I'm building. I am trying to reduce the size of an enum by using ThinBox<[T]> to store contents in a fixed length array without the whole const generics monomorphization business happening in my code (since I need to store this in an enum later and don't want to have a const generic on the level of the enum).

The closest thing I got to a solution is to ThinBox a fixed sized array. (it coerces to a slice). Though it technically does fix the problem of const generics on the type level, I want to find a solution that doesn't require me to input const generics into a function (since it's a lot less flexibility). I also don't want to end up with a ThinBox<&[T]> since that is two levels of indirection.

Is there a method, safe or unsafe, that can initialize a ThinBox<[T]> without directly hacking the compiler?

Comment: Please share what code you have and what you've tried.

Comment: What determines the size of the array? Also, perhaps the `thin-vec` crate would be a better alternative: https://crates.io/crates/thin-vec.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ThinBox::new_unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.ThinBox.html#method.new_unsize) like this:

```rust
ThinBox::<[T]>::new_unsize([/* your array */])
```